# How to install fresh requests lib in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x, python-requests

In ubuntu ubuntu-desktop needs python3-requsts package. But this package contain out-dated requests lib (2.4, current - 2.7). I need fresh version of requests, but i cant install him.

```
$ sudo pip3 install requests --upgrade
Downloading/unpacking requests from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/r/requests/requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=564fb256f865a79f977e57b79d31659a
  Downloading requests-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (470kB): 470kB downloaded
Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.4.3
    Not uninstalling requests at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

Is exist way to install fresh requests in ubuntu 15.04 without virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd better be using virtualenv  :-).

The clean way to do what you are asking is creating an OS package (a ".deb") with the newer version and installing it with dpkg.

The "unclean" way would be to delete the system-package using apt-get, synaptic, etc... and then use pip to install it on the system Python. That is bad even when the Python package does not conflict with a system created one. Again: virtualenvs are your friend.

(Note that you can create a virtualenv that does not hide your other system-packages - with the `--system-site-packages` option)

Comment: Remove the package is not the right way, because with it will be deleted and ubuntu-desktop. Thanks for the tip with virtualenv!

Comment: You overwrote the package files without deleting it from the package system: this means that your newer version is subject to be randomly overwritten by the automatic system updates, at any time and with no warning.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, i solved this problem by manually installing requests. Just download archive with package and run:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

This will remove apt-get files and install fresh version.

Comment: As I've detailed on my answer this will more likely than not break your system. Soon.